# Create criteria using Criteria Builder to query fields of concrete child class of abstract parent class

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, abstract-class, criteria-api, single-table-inheritance

I working on a requirement where user enters a text and I need to show matching data on screen.

I am using EclipseLink as JPA provider.

Following is the code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer{
     private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
 //other code
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Table(name="address")
public abstract class Address{
private String name;

}

@Entity
public class PostalAddress extends Address{
private Contact number;
}

public class Contact{
  private String number;
  public Contact(String number){
  this.number = number;
  }
}
```

In DataBase I have table 'address' in which I have columns 'name' and 'number'.

I want to create a Predicate using CriteriaBuilder to search a specific value in table.

I have tried using

```
criteriabuiler.like(criteriabuiler.lower(root.join("addresses", JoinType.LEFT).<String>get("number")), searchString));
```

But it gives exception as

```
The attribute [msisdn] from the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@27575562:Address] is not present.
```

Can you please suggest a way to implement this thing?